# Acessing Multiple Functions Inside Single Function In an Object

Tags: javascript, html, function

So I Have The Code as Follows:

```
const Solver = new Object
Solver.circle = function(r){
area = Math.PI * r**2
perimeter = Math.PI * 2*r 
return "Area:" + area + " Perimeter:" + perimeter
}
```

Now I Would Like To Get the value of area and perimeter seperately like using Something like this

```
Solver.circle(2).area  \\ 12.57
Solver.circle(2).perimeter \\ 12.57
Solver.circle(2)  \\ Area:12.57 Perimeter:12.57
```

Is there any way i could achieve something like this. If Not What could be the best Alternative Other than having different Main Functions like `Solve.circlearea(2)` or `Solve.circleperi(2)`

Comment: Why not send in a secondary parameter? Solver.circle(2,area) and then handle the input as a switchcase or if statements. Also enables you to add more calculations to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Just return an object!

```js
const Solver = new Object
  Solver.circle = function(r){
  area = Math.PI * r**2
  perimeter = Math.PI * 2*r 
  return {area, perimeter}
}
```

Note that you can also do `return {area: area, perimeter: perimeter}`, but it is not necessary and JS will understand you even if you don't do that. So here you are just returning an object and in your usage you are calling the function and accessing the property from the returned object.

If you replace your function with this, your API example will work as is!

Comment: Works As I Wanted. Thanks !

Comment: You're most welcome! Please consider accepting my answer in that case \m/

Comment: I Have To Wait For 10mins After Posting The Question To Accept An Answer.